# Criteria Query Equal Date

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

Could someone help me, i'm trying create a query to recovery all entries with some date... everything works fine except as i try:

```
criteriaQuery.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("dadosBoleto").get("dataVencimento").as(Date.class), new Date()));
```

or

```
criteriaQuery.select(root).where(builder.equal(root.get("dadosBoleto").<Date>get("dataVencimento"), new Date()));
```

When i execute this statement i haven't any data even existing the this criteria.

My entity with dataVencimento

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "data_vencimento", nullable = false)
@NotNull(message = "Data inválida")
private Date dataVencimento;
//getters and setters
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I've added the parameter to query `ParameterExpression<Date> date = builder.parameter(Date.class);` and `manager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).setParameter(date, new Date(), TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();`